# multithreading windows apache server

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, apache, flask

I'm working with apache 2.2, I had tried to run 2 threads (parallel) but I seeming it's not working the two threads running sequentially.

### How can I force that to running simultaneously (parallel) ??

test.wsgi::

```
import time

def application(environ, start_response):

    status = '200 OK'

    output = str(time.time())
    time.sleep(5)
    output += '<br/>' + str(time.time())
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return [output]
```

---

I had inserted at the the end of httpd.conf the following:

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf

<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
        ThreadsPerChild   253
        MaxRequestsPerChild     0
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost *>
        ServerName localhost    
        WSGIScriptAlias / C:\test\test.wsgi
        <Directory C:\test>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

---

I'm getting thats works but not parallely,

The 1st thread: 
1374420108.56
1374420113.56

The 2nd thread:
1374420113.57
1374420118.57

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved, it's seeming to be "test misuse", I had test that with multiple tabs with the same browser, but somehow the browser doesn't handle these multiple concurrent requests, so I tried that with different browsers and it's working !!